# Permissions for Win 7

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Please! I have no computer knowledge for certain issues at hand and really need for some kind and patient soul to help me. I do not understand Permissions and wonder if their is a list showing the default permissions in Win 7. Like a cheat sheet for dummies??

Comment: [Understanding Windows NTFS Permissions](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html)

Comment: [How to Understand Those Confusing Windows 7 File/Share Permissions](http://www.howtogeek.com/72718/how-to-understand-those-confusing-windows-7-fileshare-permissions/)

Comment: [Establishing File & Folder Level Permissions: Windows 7](http://www.uwec.edu/Help/drives/permissions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) You can find a table with how permissions look like.

[Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7) It is explained how to change them. This may look complicated at start.

And [here](http://www.uwec.edu/Help/drives/permissions.htm) you have a practical example.

Note that windows Vista and above are made with 'dumb-mode on', meaning it will not allow you to do anything important without running things in a special elevated access mode. This applies also for administrators. Windows runs things in user mode even if the logged in account is admin.